# Format Currency Excel

Tags: excel, formatting, ms-office, number-formatting

I have multiple files that contain currency fields but do not separate the dollars from cents.

I need to go through each one and fix the format to get the totals

Ex.

```
Number 1      Number 2
00001575041   00000421990
```

Needs to be formatted as

```
15750.41      4219.90
```

So that I can get a total of the two numbers.

Looking for the most efficient way to complete this task and any help is appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your value in **A1**, in **C1** enter:

```
=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2)+RIGHT(A1,2)/100
```

[image]